# No playback devices on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, audio

I don't see any playback devices in Windows XP.

I've done my research on it but still no luck. I have seen and tried this solution:

> 1. Click on Start and Run
> 2. Type the following command and press Enter
>
>    ```
>    services.msc
>    ```
> 3. Scroll down to Windows Audio in the right-hand column and
>      double-click on it,
> 4. Make sure the Startup Type is set to Automatic and click on the
>      Start button under Service Status. The Windows Audio service should
>      restart and the error with the volume control should be resolved.

… but it doesn't work for me.

Could it be that my PC has no sound card?

I also check my device manager list and here is what I've found:

- Audio Codecs
- Legacy Audio Drivers
- Media Control Device
- Legacy Video Capture Devices
- Video Codecs

Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consult information about your motherboard, and ideally:

> Track down a support DVD for it, that contains drivers and software.
>
> Follow it's installation process for Audio Drivers.

It looks like Windows XP doesn't have drivers to support your particular playback devices.

I have had this issue on older laptops moving them to Vista and Windows 7.

Comment: so, my pc has a bulit-in sound card has it?

Comment: Probably, depending on it's age, if you post specs of the machine then we can help more

Answer (score 0):

Does your PC have audio ports? (most do). If so, it has a sound card, most likely. Posting your exact configuration or at least a model would help somewhat, but looking at the rear of the system is the simplest thing i can think of