# How to obtain your motherboard specs via software?

Tags: windows-xp, motherboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find out what the motherboard on my computer is](https://superuser.com/questions/175213/find-out-what-the-motherboard-on-my-computer-is)

Is there any reliable software to obtain the specs of your motherboard?

This question is related to the one that I have posted before [link here](https://superuser.com/questions/336263/no-playback-devices-on-windowsxp).

Forget the link, is there any other process to get the information without opening your system unit?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest [CPU-Z from CPUID](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html)   It is an excellent utility, lightweight, requires no install, and gives accurate stats.  Go to the link and check out the screenshot to see all the info it can display.

Answer (score 1):

If your system is running and working, you can use something like [pcwizard](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/pc-wizard.html) or [SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/) - both of this uses WMI, and should be accurate even if the drivers for the device arn't installed (or device manager - all devices should be there, and driverless ones should have a !). In linux systems the lshw command does the same thing.